# How to recognize and execute multiple commands from a phrase in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have created a program that listens our voice using google speech recognition and then execute the program which is scripted for that phrase.
Here is the partial code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

def takeCommand():
    #It takes microphone input from the user and returns string output

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")    
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print("User said: ",query)

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)    
        print("Say that again please...")
        os.startfile('JARVIS.py')
        os._exit()
        return "None"
    return query

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        command_history()
        # Logic for executing tasks based on query
        if 'chrome' in query:
            os.startfile("C:/............./chrome.exe")
        elif 'photoshop' in query:
            os.startfile("C:/............../photoshop.exe")
```

It works fine, but what if I want to recognize multiple commands from the voice?
For example, if I would say, "**open chrome and photoshop**", then it will only open chrome because it is listed first, and after that the program will end.
But I want to extract every command from the speech, So, how to do it?

*Any help will be considered great, and sorry for my bad english*

Comment: Try to add a list of common task that you want to be executed and then, after the voice has been converted to text you can see if there are multiple tasks to be executed. I might publish the full solution if this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program ends at chrome because you are using an if-elif. Try with if...if

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually make an AI like that with just a bunch of `if-elif-else` statements. For tasks like those that you want to achieve, you should go for things like Natural Language Processing. Python modules like [`spacy`](https://spacy.io) can you help with that. First you should extract what the user said (which you are doing very well) and then give that to an Natural Language Processing algorithm that can provide you with the *intent* of the speech and after that you should go ahead with execution.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a tutorial for spacy, as I don't know a single thing about nlp

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've been developing a solution to this problem: CommandsGPT.
It takes an instruction as an input (for example, "Read my clipboard, write a scientific article about the content in it. If I like it, save it as a file with a name related to the article.", and produces a graph of commands that will be executed (you can define your own commands using natural language and coding the functions!). It's really easy and intuitive to use.

You can install it via `pip install commandsgpt`
Here's my repo: https://github.com/AlexisAndradeDev/CommandsGPT

Comment: Also, you can use OpenAI's Whisper model to recognize speech. It's incredibly precise.

Comment: You'll need an OpenAI API Key.